# Python condition computation

Tags: python

I'm curious, why in python this expression produces False:

```
>>> False == True != True
False
```

For comparsion, js:

```
> false == true != true
true
```

golang:

```
fmt.Println(false == true != true) => true
```

And I can explain why js and golang have such results: if you compute this expression from left to right, you will get false != true, which is true. 
How does python interpret this code to get False?

Comment: The weird thing is that `False != True != True` also returns `False`.

Comment: Dupe helps, just note that `==` and `!=` have the same operator precedence as `is`. https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons

Comment: Maybe python can't interpret 3 T/F statements in a row.
False == (True != True) returns True